# Writing and reading to child process via pipes doesn't work

Tags: c, unix, exec, posix, pipe

As an exercise in Unix programming I wrote a program which creates two pipes, forks a child and then sends and receives some text to and from the child via the pipes. It works if in the child process I read and write the data using my code in function `filter`. However, if the child tries to redirect the pipes to its stdin and stdout (using `dup2`) and execute (using `execlp`) the `tr` utility, then it doesn't work, it gets stuck somewhere. This code is in the `filter2` function. The question is, why? Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void err_sys(const char* x) { perror(x); exit(1); } 

void upper(char *s) { while((*s = toupper(*s))) ++s; }

void filter(int input, int output)
{   
    char buff[1024];
    bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));
    size_t n = read(input, buff, sizeof(buff));

    printf("process %ld: got '%s'\n", (long) getpid(), buff);

    upper(buff);
    write(output, buff, strlen(buff));
}   

void filter2(int input, int output)
{   
    if (dup2(input, 0) != 0) err_sys("dup2(input, 0)");
    if (dup2(output, 1) != 1) err_sys("dup2(output, 1)");
    execlp("/usr/bin/tr", "tr", "[a-z]", "[A-Z]" , (char*)0);
}   

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{   
    int pipe1[2];
    int pipe2[2];
    if (pipe(pipe1) < 0) err_sys("pipe1");
    if (pipe(pipe2) < 0) err_sys("pipe2");

    pid_t pid;
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) err_sys("fork");
    else if (pid > 0)
    {   
        close(pipe1[0]);
        close(pipe2[1]);
        char* s = "Hello there, can you please uppercase this and send it back to me? Thank you!";
        write(pipe1[1], s, strlen(s));

        char buff[1024];
        bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));
        size_t n = read(pipe2[0], buff, sizeof(buff));
        pid_t mypid = getpid();
        printf("process %ld: got '%s'\n", (long) mypid, buff);
    } else
    {   // Child.
        close(pipe1[1]);
        close(pipe2[0]);

        filter(pipe1[0], pipe2[1]); 
        //filter2(pipe1[0], pipe2[1]);  // FIXME: This doesn't work
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please define "doesn't work".

Comment: try `char argv[] = {"tr", "[a-z]", "[A-Z]", NULL}; execvp(*argv, argv);`

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov the `tr` process is blocked on read(0, ..., as I see in the output of strace

Comment: @SergeyL. using `execvp` instead of `execlp` does not change anything, I just checked it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parent process in main needs a small change:

```
/* Was: */
char* s = "Hello there, can you please uppercase this and send it back to me? Thank you!";
write(pipe1[1], s, strlen(s));
/* add: */
close(pipe1[1]);
```

Other people have mentioned buffering, but it's not really a buffering issue. It's about interprocess communication.

There is a reason why pipes are called 'pipes' and not, say, 'conveyor belts'. Pipes, unlike conveyor belts, don't retain package boundaries. A pipe is just a stream of bytes; `write` dumps a bunch of bytes into the stream, but does not mark the fact that it has done so. Consequently, your code could have identically been:

```
    write(pipe1[1], s, strlen(s)/2);
    write(pipe1[1], s + strlen(s)/2,
                    strlen(s+strlen(s)/2));
```

or any other combination of `write`s. The receiving end will just read a convenient number of bytes (convenient to it, that is), and process them. It probably does something like this:

```
     read(stdin, buffer, BUFSIZ);
```

which will not return until either BUFSIZ bytes have been read, or until EOF is reached. Since you cannot reach into the reading process's system calls and retroactively change the length of the read, the only way you can get the reading process to actually finish its work is to arrange for it to get an EOF indication, and the only way you can do that is to close the pipe. Hence my solution above.

That's not always convenient, because it makes it impossible to put two consecutive requests into a stream. There is quite a lot of overhead involved in establishing communication between two processes (particularly if the server process needs to be started fresh). If you want to "pipeline" requests (so that responses are sent at the end of every request), you need to design a communications protocol which clearly indicates the "package boundaries"; the division between the requests. In other words, you need to implement your own conveyor belt, using a pipe.

A communications protocol requires support from both ends; you cannot just implement it from the client. So you're not going to be able to get `tr` to understand an arbitrary protocol; it just does what it does (reads to EOF and writes translated bytes when it feels it has enough of them to bother sending). So if you want to play around with this idea, you'll need to write both the client and the server process.

The simplest package protocol available is probably Daniel Bernstein's [netstrings](http://cr.yp.to/proto/netstrings.txt). The link contains actual code, which is delightfully simple, but the basic idea is this: strings are sent by sending their length as a decimal number, followed by a colon (:), followed by exactly the number of bytes promised in the length. The writer needs to know how many bytes it will send before it sends them; the reader needs to read up to the ':' (djb uses `scanf` to do this, which demonstrates an often underappreciated feature of `scanf`); once it knows how many bytes are in the request, it can then block read exactly that number of bytes. This is a trivial protocol to implement on both sides, so it makes for a simple practical exercise.

HTTP uses a similar but much more complicated protocol (and, as with all unnecessarily complicated protocols, the result is that interoperability bugs were common because of misunderstanding), but in essence it's the same: the sender needs to indicate how long the message (or body of the message, in the case of HTTP) is, which it does with a `Content-Length:` header. However, since it is not always convenient to know how many bytes you're going to send before you send them all, HTTP allows "chunked" encoding (indicated with a different header); in that case, each chunk consists of a length (in hexadecimal), followed by `\r\n` followed by the body, followed by `\r\n`, followed by... well, you can read the RFC for the messy details. Problems here include the fact that some clients send just `\n` instead of `\r\n` and that it is slight ambiguous how to handle the trailing `\r\n`. Netstrings, as djb points out, would have been a lot simpler.

Unless you want to use a full HTTP client/server library, a more practical alternative for implementing interprocess communications is Google's open-sourced [protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) package. For an earlier and in my opinion technically-superior solution, which unfortunately does not have a convenient set of open-source tools, is [ASN.1](http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/asn1/introduction/index.htm) (but don't plunge into that site right away; it's big).

Comment: hey, thanks for that. But... do you think any of those things you described are used by, for example, the expect program? I haven't yet time to analyze expect's source properly, but I think it does something with pseudo teletypes (pty).

Comment: @piokuc, no, expect just reads a character at a time, and relies on the fact that ptys also read a character at a time. I guess that is the absolute simplest communications protocol, but it's far from the most efficient. A similar protocol is so-called "line-at-a-time", but that reduces to character-at-a-time because you really have to check every character to see if it is a line-end.

Comment: @piokuc, by the way, I'm pretty sure that `tr` just uses the standard C library for I/O, reading one character at a time from stdin and writing one character at a time to stdout. The standard library line-buffers output if stdout is a tty (which includes ptys, luckily, since very few of us still have real serial consoles, but does not include pipes or sockets).

Comment: there must be a way to wrap a pipe or socket in a pty, no?

Comment: @piokuc, not really. pty's are very weird beasts, which effectively wrap a kernel console (the thing that used to be a serial console). When you telnet (or ssh) to a login process on a host, there is a pty on the far side. If you telnet from a shell, there's a pty on the local side, too. That makes the socket into a transparent byte-oriented connection between ptys, but it's not in any way wrapping the socket.

Comment: OK, I can see I used a wrong word. Would it be better to say that the pipe needs to be connected to a `pty`, so the `tr` process thinks its input comes from a terminal?

Comment: @piokuc, I'd say it would be better to close the pipe, as in my answer. The cost of setting up communications through a pty is probably more than starting up a new `tr`. There are only a limited number of ptys, and despite the name, they really are tty-like (for example, they expect terminal-emulated input and produce terminal-emulated output, so they're not 8-bit transparent). There are other issues, too. But trying it would be an interesting exercise, I guess. :)

Comment: yeah, exactly, it's just an exercise. I will setup the pty and see how it works. It will take some time as I am busy with real work. But Steven's book is already open on relevant page.. :) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The most probable issue here is that both [`stdin`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/stdio.3.html) and [`stdout`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/stdio.3.html) streams are *line-buffered* by default, so the `tr` process is working, just not getting its input/not flushing stream into the pipe. Try sending more input to the child process, you'll see it responding, but ...

- Be careful with string zero terminators - right now you are printing bytes read from a pipe that might not be a proper C-syle zero-terminated string,
- Check return values of all system calls like [`write(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/write.2.html),
- *Avoid race conditions* - currently you have both parent and child blocked waiting on input, you might want to switch to non-blocking mode and use [`select(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html) for IO multiplexing.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the line-buffering, notice that I don't use any high-level C functions for reading/writing, but the low level ones (read & write). I just changed the program to add couple of '\n' at the end the message, but it doesn't help. I'll see if sending more text makes the `tr`'s `read` to complete.

Answer (score 1):

`tr` is blocking on read because it uses buffered input.

If you don't want to write more, just close the pipe when you're finished writing (and before reading).

Comment: I would prefer to start reading from the child process before finishing writing to it. Let's say it's an interactive program, like a scripting language interpreter. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure, you need some way to disable buffering for interactive use. See, for example, [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25372/14898) (recommending expect's unbuffer command, or GNU stdbuf ... you'd use them to wrap the `tr` child process)

Comment: Thanks, I'll investigate the buffering stuff.

Answer (score 0):

`write(pipe1[1], s, strlen(s));` does not write the NUL-character, but this would be necessary for `while((*s = toupper(*s))) ++s;`

Comment: No. The whole buffer is initialized with 0, so after the copied text there is a 0. Anyway, the question was not about the code in function `filter`, which works, but about function `filter2` (you need to uncomment it and comment out `filter`).